# Don't trigger hover event on children

Tags: jquery, css

I have a container with tiles (grass, water, etc) and in some of them I have items (border-sprites, trees, and general items). Due to the nature of the sprites, all items are 64x64 while tiles are only 32x32.

My problem is that I want to trigger a hover event on tiles, but they are sometimes shadowed by another tiles' items.

The image below shows the problem. The thick green area is the tile that **really** gets hovered when I want to hover the tree-tile.

[the problem http://upload.cip.nu/pfile.php?file_id=2327](http://upload.cip.nu/pfile.php?file_id=2327)

The CSS:

```css
#map_canvas .tile{
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
}
#map_canvas .tile .item{
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

The HTML, simplified:

```html
<div class="tile" style="background-image: url(grass.png);"></div>
<div class="tile" style="background-image: url(grass.png);"></div>
<div class="tile" style="background-image: url(grass.png);">
    <div class="item" style="background-image(top-left-border.png);"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the live demo http://sleavely.com/tiles/

I don't even know how to phrase the question, but here goes:

Is it possible to only trigger the event on the parent element (.tile) so that overflowing children (.item) do not obfuscate which tile I really hover?

**EDIT: Thanks to @Brilliand I implemented the following**

```js
function figureOutTile(e){
    var $source = jQuery(e.srcElement);
    if($source.hasClass("item")){
        var $parent = $source.parent();
        var posx = $parent.attr("col");
        var posy = $parent.attr("row");
        if(e.offsetY <= 32){
            if(e.offsetX <= 32){
                return jQuery(".tile[col="+ (posx-1) +"][row="+ (posy-1) +"]");
            }else{
                return jQuery(".tile[col="+ posx +"][row="+ (posy-1) +"]");
            }
        }else{
            if(e.offsetX <= 32){
                return jQuery(".tile[col="+ (posx-1) +"][row="+ posy +"]");
            }else{
                return $parent;
            }
        }
    }else{
        return $source;
    }
}
jQuery("#map_viewport").on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        var $target = figureOutTile(e);
        $target.addClass('hovered');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        jQuery(".tile.hovered").removeClass('hovered');
    }
}, '.tile');​
```

Comment: Can we see your javascript? Nothing in the code you posted so far refers to hover.

Comment: Wow, this is a very specific question. But I think it boils down to event bubbling.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Right now it's basically just a `jQuery("#map_viewport").on("hover", ".tile", function(e){` that I use to toggle a class on the tile. The issue is that the event triggers on the wrong tile.

Comment: hmmm, its still not really enough info for me. Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but do'nt use `on('hover', function() {...});` either use jQuery's `hover()` or `mouseenter`  / `mouseleave`.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I edited with a link at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as your browser is concerned, hovering over something sticking out of a tile is the same as hovering over the tile that it's sticking out of, not hovering over whatever is being covered up.  To work around this in your specific situation, I suggest putting your hover function on #map_canvas, and working out in that function which tile is being hovered over.  For tiles in a rectangular grid, this is simple arithmetic.

Of course, for this to work you will need to include a mousemove event (to detect when the mouse moves from one tile to another), and you should probably include code to exit the function if the user is still hovering over the same tile.

EDIT: Although this answer has already been accepted, here's a solution based on my comment:

```
$(".tile").append($("<div/>", {
    css: {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        "z-index": 50
    }
}));
```

This seems to fix the problem for all of the tiles with items on them, though it screws up your :empty declarations.  I mention it mainly because it comes closer to answering your question as asked.

Comment: It might also work to insert an empty absolutely-positioned div with a high z-index over each tile; this might be able to intercept the hover event before it reaches the overlapping item.

Comment: I think I'll try this solution out later on, since it probably doesn't need Javascript at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".tile").children().on('mouseenter', function(e) { 
   e.stopPropogation(); 
});
```

or

```
$(".tile").on('mouseenter', function(e) { 
   if (this===e.target) {
      //do stuff
   }
});
```

EDIT:

```
$("#map_viewport").on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (this===e.target) {
            $(element).addClass('someClass')
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(element).removeClass('someClass')
    }
}, '.tile');
```

Comment: I tried your second and third example, neither of which worked. The third example only triggered on tiles that were child-less and had no neighboring tiles with items on them. :(

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If it is indeed a problem with event bubbling and you are using jQuery, check out the [event.stopPropagation method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Have you tried adding `z-index`es?

```
    #map_canvas .tile{
        height: 32px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 32px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    #map_canvas .tile .item{
        background-position: bottom right;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        bottom: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 64px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

Comment: event.stopPropagation only hinders the event from bubbling up, not from coming from a child. :(

I'm not sure I understand the purpose of z-index in this context, though.